# Proper way to define function in a class that does not use self value

Tags: python

I am new to opp programming.I wanted to know what to do with a function that is inside the class but does not use self value

For example

```
class example:


      def __init__(self,n):
          self.number=n
      def get_t(self,t):
          return t*t 
      def main(self):
          b=1
          k=self.get_t(b)
```

From the example the function get_t has nothing to do with self value.

So I wanted to know where to place the function get_t or may be how to restructure the class.

Thank you for your consideration

Comment: This depends highly on your use-case. If it is not related to your class at all, it may be best to place such "methods" outside of a class as regular functions. You can also decorate it as a ``staticmethod``, in which case it does not receive ``self``. In the latter case, there is a good chance it should be private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for are static methods. To declare a method static do it like this

```
@staticmethod
def foo():
    pass
```

Comment: Can a static method be call inside the class and how? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it can. Via the class name like `MyClass.foo()` or via `self.foo()` as well.

Comment: Thanks,but will it be cleaner to declare another class separately to define this function.

Comment: Since it (apparently) has nothing to do with the class itself, it would be cleaner to make it a plain function, not inside any class.

Answer (score 2):

1. Nothing. Just let it be, Python won't complain about it and there's nothing fundamentally wrong about methods that doesn't use its instance. If your linter complains about it, you can shut up that warning. These kind of helper functions are often intended to be private methods that aren't intended to be used externally, you may want to prefix the name with underscore to indicate that.
2. Convert it into a free function. Python is an OOP language, but it's also a mixed paradigm language, unlike Java, for example, you can actually create a function outside of a class declaration. Pythonic code does not necessarily means putting everything into classes, and often a free function is perfectly suitable place for functions that doesn't involve a particular object instance.

   ```
   def get_t(t):
       return t*t
   class example:
       def main(self):
           b=1
           k=self.get_t(b)
   ```
3. If you want to be able to call it from the class by doing `Example.get_t(blah)` without having to have an instance, then you can either use the staticmethod or classmethod decorator. I suggest using classmethod which can do everything that staticmethod can do while the reverse isn't true and it's easier to make classmethod work correctly when you need to override it in a multi inheritance situation. staticmethod has a very tiny performance advantage, but you're microoptimizing if that's your concern.

   ```
   class example:
       @classmethod
       def get_t(cls, t):
           return t*t 
       def main(self):
           b=1
           k=self.get_t(b)
   ```
4. If get_t() is only being called from one method, you can put it as an inner function of that method:

   ```
   class example:
       def main(self):
           def get_t(t):
               return t * t
           b=1
           k=self.get_t(b)
   ```

---

With regards to naming, `get_xxx` is usually a code smell in python. The `get_` prefix indicates that the method is likely a getter, and pythonic code usually don't use getters/setters, because the language supports property. What you have on here though, isn't actually a getter but rather a computation method, so it shouldn't be prefixed with `get_`. A better name might be calculate_t(t) or square(t).

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1**: If `self` is there:-

```
class example:
    def get_t(self,t):
        return t*t
```

Then You can not access `get_t` function directly from class `example` like `example.get_t(t=2)` ,it will give you error.  But you can access now by creating an object of class like `q = example()` and then `q.get_t(t=2)` , it will give you your desired result.

**Case 2** : If `self` is not there:-

```
class example:
    def get_t(t):
        return t*t
```

Now You can directly access `get_t` function by class `example` like `example.get_t(t=2)` ,it will give you your desired result. But now you cannot use `get_t` function by creating object like `q = example()` then `q.get_t(t=2)` it will give you error.

**Conclusion** :- It all depends on your use case. But when you struck in this type of ambiguity use `@staticmethod` like given below:-

```
class example:
    @staticmethod
    def get_t(t):
        return t*t
```

I hope it may help you.